# What vanilla javascript api can I use to determine if an image has finished loading?

Tags: javascript, html, image, dom

The functionality of image.onload is what I'm looking for, but the method is listed in the MDN archive of obsolete content: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Mozilla/XUL/Attribute/image.onload

Comment: I don't think it is deprecated. It is working. Check here example https://codepen.io/bhavik103/pen/abzvVVd

Comment: What's `XUL`? I don't think it was deprecated

Comment: Correction, not deprecated but listed in the MDN archive of obsolete content.

Answer (score 3):

The page you are looking at is about the **XUL** (XML User Interface Language) `<image>` element.

[The whole language is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Mozilla/XUL), hence the notice.

The one you are looking for is the [HTMLImageElement (`<img>`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement), on which the [load](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event)  event will fire, and for long in the future ;-).